# R add legend to plot

Tags: r, loops, title

I wrote the following script to generate several plot in a for loop which works well:

```
stat <- list.files("D:/...", pattern = "met")

par(mfrow = c(4, 4))
for (x in stat) {
plot((assign(x, read.csv(x, head=TRUE, sep=""))),typ="l", col="red")
}
```

What I would like to achieve now is to add the title of each graph recursively according to the name of the file that is read.

Hope this is clear,

Best,

P.S.
I also have another curiosity but I will leave this maybe for after.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does adding the title (`main`) argument to `plot` do what you're looking for?

```
plot((assign(x, read.csv(x, head=TRUE, sep=""))),typ="l", col="red", main=x)
```

edited for OPs comment

you can use `gsub` for this.

```
plot((assign(gsub('\\.txt', '', x), 
      read.csv(x, head=TRUE, sep=""))),
     typ="l", 
     col="red", 
     main=gsub('\\.txt', '', x))
```

However, the looping assign construct you're using is a dangerous one to get in the habit of using.  Usually this would be done by reading all the files in as a list and then `lapply` across them, or some variation on that theme.

You should be able to skip the `assign` step altogether unless you're doing additional processing after this plot step.

```
plot(read.csv(x, head=TRUE, sep=""),
     typ="l",
     col="red",
     main=gsub('\\.txt', '', x))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly. But I have another question. Since the name of the file finish with .txt i will also have this in the title: is there a way to remove this and keep just the part of the title that I need. Hope this is clear. Thanks again

Comment: This would be best added as a different question, but see my edits.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was searching for.